# Switching activity layout according to the button pressed in previous activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-button

I am a beginner in java and android.
I have a categories activity with two buttons & the game activity with two layouts.I want to let the game activity detect which button is pressed in categories and set its corresponding layout by this way:

```
    if (Case_A)
   setContentView(R.layout.layout1);

   else if (Case_B)
   setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
```

With what code should I replace "Case_A" and "Case_B" to detect the button press ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `Intent` you can pass a value to `GameActivity`

```
Intent i = new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
i.putExtra("layout", "layout1");
startActivity(i);
```

then in your `GameActivity` in your `onCreate()`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String layout = intent.getStringExtra("layout");
if (layout.equals("layout1")
   setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
   else if (Case_B)
   setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
```

This is one way to just pass any value you want depending on which `Button` was pressed. You also could get the `Button` text, `id`, or whatever you want and pass that.